# How to make pageview indicator change position

Tags: flutter, pageviews

How to make pageview indicator to change position like in first pageview page the indicators are position center bottom and next page (sliding to next page) are the indicators andimated to top right corner?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwMZD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use Hero transition. Look at this:

```
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations
```